# Pass object attribute to form and get it back

Tags: spring, jpa, thymeleaf

I got a model like this:

```
@Entity
public class DayMenuItem {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private MonetaryAmount price;
    private Product product;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = DayMenu.class)
    private DayMenu dayMenu;

    ...
}
```

with getters and setters. And I have the DayMenu model, that has an id attribute as well.

I create a new instance of the DayMenuItem class, set the corresponding dayMenu attribute and pass it to a view. In the view the user can set the other properties like price or name. **I now want to forward the dayMenu attribute to the next controller by passing it in a hidden input field.** My thymeleaf view form looks like this:

```
<form th:acction="@{/admin/addMenuItem}" th:object="${menuitem}" method="post">
    <p>Name: </p><input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
    <p>Price: </p><input type="text" th:field="*{price}"/>
    <button>Ok</button>
    <input type="hidden" th:field="${menuitem.dayMenu}" th:value="${menuitem.getDayMenu()}"/>
</form>
```

JPA(?) picks the (correct) DayMenu Id as the value of the hidden input. But when I try to get the Model back into a controller, it doesn't accept the Id value anymore.

My controller head looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/addMenuItem", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addMenuItemPost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("menuitem") DayMenuItem dayMenuItem,
                                    BindingResult bindingResultDayMenuItem,
                                    ModelAndView modelAndView) { ...
```

When I take a look at the BindingResult, I see this error and the dayMenu attribute is null.
(1 is the DayMenu id)

> org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'menuitem' on field 'dayMenu': rejected value [1]; codes [typeMismatch.menuitem.dayMenu,typeMismatch.dayMenu,typeMismatch.winetavern.model.menu.DayMenu,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [menuitem.dayMenu,dayMenu]; arguments []; default message [dayMenu]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [winetavern.model.menu.DayMenu] for property 'dayMenu'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.ManyToOne winetavern.model.menu.DayMenu] for value '1'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.salespointframework.core.SalespointIdentifier]

Why does JPA not accept the ID as identifier of the object anymore and throws an exception, although it once did the conversion from the object to the ID value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found the probably best solution. I put an initBinder in my controller class looking like this one:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(DayMenu.class, "dayMenu", new PropertyEditorSupport() {
        @Override
        public String getAsText() {
            DayMenu dayMenu = (DayMenu) getValue();
            return String.valueOf(dayMenu.getId());
        }
        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) {
            DayMenu dayMenu = dayMenuRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(text));
            setValue(dayMenu);
        }
    });
}
```

The getAsText() return value is taken as the hidden input value and the setAsText() method gets called when the form input gets passed to the controller.

Answer (score 2):

spring  wont be able to infer Object from the supplied string

try,

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="dayMenu" th:value="${menuitem.getDayMenu()}"/>
```

---

```
    @ModelAttribute("menuitem")
    public DayMenuItem  getDayMenuItem (@RequestParam String dayMenu){      
        DayMenuItem item = new DayMenuItem();
        DayMenu mi = new DayMenu();
        mi.setId(dayMenu);
        item.setDayMenu(mi);
        return  item ;
    }



@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/addMenuItem", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addMenuItemPost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("menuitem") DayMenuItem dayMenuItem,
                                    BindingResult bindingResultDayMenuItem,
                                    ModelAndView modelAndView){..}
```